# Need to loop through an array to determine output

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to output an address like this 123 Street, address, city, county, postcode

The data is stored in a database and i need to check to see if the field has anything in it so I know to output a comma in the address

```
$address = array($club['clubAdd1'], $club['clubAdd2'], $clubCity, $club['clubCounty'], $club['clubPostcode']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$parts = array(

  $club['clubAdd1'],
  $club['clubAdd2'],
  $clubCity,
  $club['clubCounty'],
  $club['clubPostcode'],

);

$address = array();

foreach ($parts as $part)
{

  if ('' != $part)
  {
    $address[] = $part;
  }

}

echo implode(', ', $address);
```

**Edit: one liner**

```
  echo implode(', ', array_filter($array));
```

**Edit 2: More accurate one liner**

The problem with the above is that `0` and `'0'` will also be removed, which might not be desired behaviour. This will fix that:

```
array_filter($array, function ($value)
{
  return strlen(trim($value));
}
);
```

Comment: This works great thanks, but why do i need two arrays? doesnt this just end up using more code?

Comment: Heh. Didn't actually look down. Just read his comment and responded. Sorry.

Comment: About "Edit 2", good point, but not likely given the OP is referring to address values.

Comment: True, but just in case the method is used in related non-address situations.

Answer (score 1):

Running the array through the [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function, without a second argument, would return an array with no empty elements.

For example:

```
$address_line = implode(', ',array_filter($address_array));
```

As Michael have noted, this would also remove nnumeric `0` values.

Answer (score 1):

a one-liner

```
echo implode(', ', array_filter(array($club['clubAdd1'], $club['clubAdd2'], $clubCity, $club['clubCounty'], $club['clubPostcode'])))
```